# GDP per industry and per region in Europe

Tags: gdp, data-request

I'm looking for a breakdown of GDP per region and industry in Europe. Do such data exist, ideally in the public domain? I'm looking for a breakdown of GDP per region and industry in Europe. Do such data exist, ideally in the public domain? If so, please identify and link to such sources.

Comment: You will probably have to choose between region (NUTS) or country and industry

Answer (score 3):

Eurostat is the way to go.

Website: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat (advised that you start from here to get where you want to be because then you see what is actually available)

GDP specifically (I think this is not what you need exactly - GDP per country over time - but its a starting point.): http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/national-accounts/data/main-tables

Keep it in mind. Need Europe+numbers? Eurostat.

Comment: Yes.  Possibly Database by themes / Economy and finance / National Accounts (ESA2010) / Detailed breakdowns of main GDP aggregates (by industry) and even then it is not simpe